# Which one is better Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Just was trying to make my SQL Azure database work in optimial state and found a query that is listed in slow access the query is

`Select Distinct(code) as code from table1 where isNull(code, '-1') != '-1'`

Table1 has about 1M records, and we just need to find unique code except null. So my question is:

1. Is there any better query for above task.
2. Does following query perform better ?

`Select Distinct(code) as code from table1 where code is not null`

SQL Estimated Execution Plan show nothing on above query but suggest to create Index for later one. I have 4-5 indexes already on table and not sure creating any new is good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer second one with index created on column 'code'. Using function in where clause can't make use of index, I think.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am concern as I already have half the table assign in indexes and it will slow down insert if I create index for every search query I have in system.

Comment: yes, you are right, better not create the index if reads is less than writes or query time is acceptable.

Comment: well, we are using SQL Azure, and though very thing looks okay, but we occansionally have slow response frm website. So we are looking to optimize site as much as we can, as our site is expecting double traffic soon.